# How does tinker work in laravel with regard to database and models.?

Tags: php, laravel-5

`php artisan tinker`

If I type in `$owner = new carfreak\Models\CarTitle();` tinker is instantiating my laravel model, right?

But if I type in `$vehicle = carfreak\Models\Car::first();` then tinker tells me that `Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'carfreak.Cars' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from 'Cars' limit 1)`.... as if it's talking direct to the database - no model involved. ?!?!?!?

(I don't have a Car or Cars model at this point, by the way)

What am I missing?

Comment: If you don't have a `Car` model why do you try to query for `Car::first()`?

Comment: Well I've  tried both.  With the car model,  I was getting the error.  So I took the modell out and still get the same error. So I'm thinking I don't really understand how tinker works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both your questions it is not just a tinker thing but will behave the same inside a route or controller, so it is more Laravel behaviour than tinker specific.

For your first question, yes, thinker will just instantiate your model class and return it.

Then, calling `Model::method` and if the `method` does not exist on the model itself, ie. like `first` laravel will create an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` and call the method on that query builder object.

So it becomes `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->first()` which returns `$this->take(1)->get($columns)->first();`. That is a normal `select` query for the columns which then hydrates a model and returns it.

So in the background a select query first takes place, before a model is returned so your table would need to exist.

Comment: Thanks Leon,  that's a great explanation